# Button in for loop

Tags: php

I am using for loop to create several buttons, like this

```
<form method="get" action="index.php">
<table width="90%"  border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                brand: <input type="text" name="brand"/>
                <input type="submit"    value="search">
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
<?php
$brand = isset($_GET['brand'])  ? $_GET['brand'] : '';
for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++){
//some code
    echo "<br><input type='button' name='Delete' value='Delete' onclick=\"this.form.action='delete.php';this.form.submit();\">";
}
?>
```

When I click submit, it will create several buttons. I want that when onclick the button, it can pass different $i to delete.php, how can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: You could add a hidden input with $i as value

Answer (score 1):

Within delete.php you can check a GET parameter (from the URL - e.g. delete.php?id=1) and handle that based on the data passed

```
for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++){
//some code
    echo "<br><input type='button' name='Delete' value='Delete' onclick=\"this.form.action='delete.php?id=$i';this.form.submit();\">";
}
```

The point of note here is `'delete.php?id=$i'`, again assuming your file handles it by id.

Within delete.php it could be handled with something like the following;

```
if(isset($_GET['id') && $_GET['id'] != '') {
    // do something here with $_GET['id']
}
```

Comment: `$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : null;`

Comment: I try to avoid using ternary when explaining things. I have my own junior developers and whilst ternary is in our codebase, it can get very confusing. If you wanted to go further with that however you could do something like;
`$id = $_GET['id'] ?? 'something else';` or `$id = $_GET['id'] ?: 'something else';`

Comment: should not be to hard to explain to junior ;) but i understand